# Go to Specific view in BWWalkthroughViewController using presentViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, presentviewcontroller

I am using BBWalkthrough (https://github.com/ariok/BWWalkthrough) and I want to go to a specific page in the BWWalkthroughViewController's UIScrollView directly from the `presentViewController` transition.

How can I do that? Note I am not using segues as the viewController is in a different storyboard.

If I do a `presentViewController()` to a child VC of the BBWalkthroughViewController instance `walk` then it presents fine but you cannot scroll away from that view (i.e. you are in the view but without the scroll function as it doesn't have any linkage to the other views).

```
func instantiateControllers(){
// Get view controllers and build the walkthrough
let stb = UIStoryboard(name: "Walkthrough", bundle: nil)
let walkthrough = stb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("walk") as! BWWalkthroughViewController
let page_A = stb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("walkA") as! UIViewController
let page_B = stb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("walkB") as! UIViewController
let page_C = stb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("walkC")as! UIViewController
let page_D = stb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("walkD")as! UIViewController
let page_E = stb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("walkE")as! UIViewController
let page_outro = stb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("walkOUT")as! UIViewController

// Attach the pages to the master
walkthrough.delegate = self
walkthrough.addViewController(page_A)
walkthrough.addViewController(page_B)
walkthrough.addViewController(page_C)
walkthrough.addViewController(page_D)
walkthrough.addViewController(page_E)
walkthrough.addViewController(page_outro) 
self.presentViewController(walkthrough, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do is going to a page number initially and keep the order of the pages isn't ?

Comment: Yes so go to the scrollview keep it all as it is and open the goto page. From there to use the scrollview as if you entered at page 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just call the `@IBAction func nextPage()` method of `walkthrough` the desired number of times. It is equivalent to emulating user page-clicks complete with animation, which is either a bug or a feature.

Either that, or just hack the source of the code -- that's the point of open source. :-) Just make the `gotoPage()` function non-private, and call it once from your code above. There's no good reason that the design makes that function private.

In either case I believe you have to do so as part of the completion handler.

Examples:

```
// Assuming you've removed 'private' from the gotoPage() function
self.presentViewController(walkthrough, animated: true) {  walkthrough.gotoPage(3) }
```

or:

```
self.presentViewController(walkthrough, animated: true) {
    for _ in 0..<3 {
        walkthrough.nextPage()
    }
}
```

Comment: I went with the gotoPage() setting it to not-private. To make it callable in viewControl I made the protocol in the delegate method:   @objc optional func gotoPage(page:Int) // go to page         However I get the error in viewController of "Use of unresolved identifier 'gotoPage'" using  IBAction func gotPage3(sender: AnyObject) {
    gotoPage(3)
  }

Comment: BWWalkthroughViewController is a concrete class, not a protocol, so you can leave out that protocol method. (Where would it go, anyway?) Only the delegate is a protocol, but that's a callback -- when the BWW object calls your VC (BWW -> controls parent VC). What we're doing here is the other way around (parent VC -> manipulates BWW).

Comment: I removed the protocol but whatever I do I can't figure out how to call the gotoPage in the viewController to be called in the BWWalkthroughViewController.

Comment: Thanks its really late in UK (2.30am) so will do it tomorrow.

Comment: The first example works perfectly, the second only goes to the second page even if I change the <3 to <13. Thank you!